# Intellij doesn't attach standard.css from GWT

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

I generated Sample Application using Intellij 14, but `standard.css` is missing both in generated artifact and when I run super dev mode configuration.

As a result of missing standard css, all widgets look ugly or will not be shown at all.

Did I configure something the wrong way or is it a bug?

Comment: Does your module contain an `<inherit>` for one of the built-in themes?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer, you already know the answer I guess :) Intellij didn't include `<inherits>` into generated project. Move your comment to answers please. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`standard.css` is part of one of the four themes coming with the GWT SDK, and is only included if the theme-specific module is inherited by your module.

You need to add:

```xml
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard' />
```

to your module to apply the "standard" theme, or possibly:

```xml
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.StandardResources' />
```

if you include the `standard.css` by your own means (using a `<link>` tag in your HTML host page, or the `StyleInjector`; i.e. this module will only copy the files to the output without *applying* them)

See also: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/style.html#GWTtheme